# ¿Correcta forma de crear tablas?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli, mysqldb

Mi pregunta es sencilla, sólo quiero saber cuáles son las partes innecesarias de mi código o si hay algún dato que le falta para que sea una consulta correcta

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS zblog;
USE zblog;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS zblog.categoria(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  id_padre INT NOT NULL,
  nombre_categoria VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  estado ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  CONSTRAINT pk_idcategoria PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
COLLATE = utf8_spanish2_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS zblog.tipo(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nombre_tipo VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  estado ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  CONSTRAINT pk_idtipo PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
COLLATE = utf8_spanish2_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS zblog.tipo_referencia(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nombre_referencia VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  estado ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  CONSTRAINT pk_idtiporeferencia PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
COLLATE = utf8_spanish2_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS zblog.permiso(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nombre_permiso VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_idpermisos PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
COLLATE = utf8_spanish2_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS zblog.usuario (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  role VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  surname VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  nick VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  image VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT 'default_user.png',
  created_at DATETIME NOT NULL,
  updated_at DATETIME NOT NULL,
  remember_token VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  estado ENUM('0', '1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  CONSTRAINT pk_idusuario PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
COLLATE = utf8_spanish2_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS zblog.articulos (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  id_tipo INT NOT NULL,
  id_categoria INT NOT NULL,
  titulo VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  fecha DATETIME NOT NULL,
  id_usuario INT NOT NULL,
  extracto VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  texto TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  thumb VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  fuente VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  created_at DATETIME NOT NULL,
  updated_at DATETIME NOT NULL,
  estado ENUM('0', '1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  CONSTRAINT pk_idarticulos PRIMARY KEY (id),
  INDEX fk_articulos_categoria (id_categoria),
  INDEX fk_articulos_tipo (id_tipo),
  INDEX fk_articulos_usuario (id_usuario),
  CONSTRAINT fk_articulos_categoria FOREIGN KEY (id_categoria) REFERENCES zblog.categoria (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_articulos_tipo FOREIGN KEY (id_tipo) REFERENCES zblog.tipo (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_articulos_usuario FOREIGN KEY (id_usuario) REFERENCES zblog.usuario (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
ENGINE = INNODB
COLLATE = utf8_spanish2_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS zblog.comments (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  id_padre INT NOT NULL,
  id_usuario INT NOT NULL,
  id_articulo INT NOT NULL,
  content TEXT NOT NULL,
  created_at DATETIME NOT NULL,
  updated_at DATETIME NOT NULL,
  estado ENUM('0', '1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  CONSTRAINT pk_idcomments PRIMARY KEY (id),
  INDEX fk_comments_articulos (id_articulo),
  INDEX fk_comments_usuario (id_usuario),
  CONSTRAINT fk_comments_articulos FOREIGN KEY (id_articulo) REFERENCES zblog.articulos (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_comments_usuario FOREIGN KEY (id_usuario) REFERENCES zblog.usuario (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
ENGINE = INNODB
COLLATE = utf8_spanish2_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS zblog.likes (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  id_usuario INT NOT NULL,
  id_articulo INT NOT NULL,
  created_at DATETIME NOT NULL,
  updated_at DATETIME NOT NULL,
  estado ENUM('0', '1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  CONSTRAINT pk_idlikes PRIMARY KEY (id),
  INDEX fk_likes_articulos (id_articulo),
  INDEX fk_likes_usuario (id_usuario),
  CONSTRAINT fk_likes_articulos FOREIGN KEY (id_articulo) REFERENCES zblog.articulos (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_likes_usuario FOREIGN KEY (id_usuario) REFERENCES zblog.usuario (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
ENGINE = INNODB
COLLATE = utf8_spanish2_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS zblog.favoritos (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  id_usuario INT NOT NULL,
  id_articulo INT NOT NULL,
  created_at DATETIME NOT NULL,
  updated_at DATETIME NOT NULL,
  estado ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  CONSTRAINT pk_idfavoritos PRIMARY KEY (id),
  INDEX fk_favoritos_usuario (id_usuario),
  INDEX fk_favoritos_articulos (id_articulo),
  CONSTRAINT fk_favoritos_usuario FOREIGN KEY (id_usuario) REFERENCES zblog.usuario (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_favoritos_articulos FOREIGN KEY (id_articulo) REFERENCES zblog.articulos (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
ENGINE = INNODB
COLLATE = utf8_spanish2_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS zblog.referencias (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  autor VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  id_tipo_referencia INT NOT NULL,
  fecha_publicacion DATE NULL,
  titulo_referencia VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  titulo_articulo VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  recuperado VARCHAR(250) NULL,
  vol_edit VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  fecha_recuperacion DATE NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_idreferencias PRIMARY KEY (id),
  INDEX fk_referencias_tiporeferencia (id_tipo_referencia),
  CONSTRAINT fk_referencias_tiporeferencia FOREIGN KEY (id_tipo_referencia) REFERENCES zblog.tipo_referencia (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
ENGINE = INNODB
COLLATE = utf8_spanish2_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS zblog.referencia_articulo (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  id_articulo INT NOT NULL,
  id_referencia INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_idreferenciaarticulo PRIMARY KEY (id),
  INDEX fk_refartc_articulos (id_articulo),
  INDEX fk_refartc_referencias (id_referencia),
  CONSTRAINT fk_refartc_articulos FOREIGN KEY (id_articulo) REFERENCES zblog.articulos (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_refartc_referencias FOREIGN KEY (id_referencia) REFERENCES zblog.referencias (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
ENGINE = INNODB
COLLATE = utf8_spanish2_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS zblog.permisos (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  id_usuario INT NOT NULL,
  id_permiso INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_idpermisos PRIMARY KEY (id),
  INDEX fk_permisos_usuario (id_usuario),
  INDEX fk_permisos_permiso (id_permiso),
  CONSTRAINT fk_permisos_usuario FOREIGN KEY (id_usuario) REFERENCES zblog.usuario (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_permisos_permiso FOREIGN KEY (id_permiso) REFERENCES zblog.permiso (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
ENGINE = INNODB
COLLATE = utf8_spanish2_ci;
```

Comment: cuando escribes `para que sea una consulta correcta` es que te esta dando algun error? si es asi colocalo en la pregunta.

Comment: No veo que consultes nada, solamente estas creando tablas si no existen

Comment: Pues de hecho no, sólo era para saber si así lo puedo dejar o si hay algo que mejorar, es mera curiosidad

Comment: Por ejemplo, realmente no entiendo la utilidad del INDEX, traté de investigar pero todavía no me queda claro, creo que debí mencionarlo

Comment: El problema es que tu pregunta es muy subjetiva. ¿Que si hay algo que mejorar? Pues depende, para responder eso habría que saber en qué contexto van a trabajar esas tablas. Puede que las tablas o sus relaciones  permitan datos redundantes por poner un ejemplo, entonces habría que controlar eso mediante índices `UNIQUE`. Puede que las consultas sean lentas porque los índices no están bien puestos, etc, etc. Todo eso solamente se puede saber conociendo a fondo el modelo de datos y dónde va a trabajar. A veces sobre la marcha uno se da cuenta que hay algo mal y tiene que corregirlo.

Comment: Oh vaya, muchas gracias, supongo que sólo era eso.

Comment: Cuando creas un modelo de datos hay varias cosas a controlar y a probar. Por ejemplo: En la tabla `X` no puede haber más de una fila con las columnas `a` y `b` repetidas. Entonces tienes que verificar que esa restricción (lógica) funciona realmente, y eso lo haces intentando insertar dos duplicados a ver si te pemite insertarlos o no (aunque lo puedes ver con los `CREATE TABLE` si tienes experiencia, siempre es bueno hacer pruebas). O por ejemplo, en la tabla `Y` no puede haber registros huérfanos en su relación con la tabla `Z`, entonces intentas crear un huérfano ahí a ver qué pasa. Y así...

Comment: Falta que encriptes la columna de contraseña, a menos de que quieras tener problemas de seguridad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues la verdad es que suscribo todo lo que te han comentado los compañeros: el diseño de tu base de datos depende de la semántica del problema que quieras modelar. En principio, has vinculado todas las tablas sin dejarte ninguna suelta, eso ya es buena señal. Si el diseño es bueno o malo, o si necesitas algún índice, lo irás viendo con el uso. Afortunadamente, el SQL es lo suficientemente flexible como para que puedas modificarlo conforme lo necesites y aprenderás sabias lecciones de cada cosa que no hayas contemplado ahora.

Tanto el modelo ER, como el diagrama de la base de datos que te adjunto, te ayudarán a repasar el caso de uso de forma que te dejes atrás lo mínimo posible. Lo cual, por otra parte, es prácticamente inevitable, porque descubrirás matices del caso de uso al que será imposible anticiparse en este momento.

Pásanos dudas concretas, será un placer ayudarte.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo, acabo de ver campos `id_padre`, que entiendo son implementaciones de relaciones monarias, que podrías definir como una `FK` a la misma tabla:

```
ALTER TABLE categoria ADD
   FOREIGN KEY(id_padre) REFERENCES categoria(id);

ALTER TABLE comments ADD
  FOREIGN KEY(id_padre) REFERENCES comments(id);
```

Comment: Ohhh ¿se puede hacer eso? Pero ¿cómo se podría hacer para las que estén hasta arriba, las que son 0 por ejemplo, 0>1 || 0>2

Comment: ¿Un diagrama de la base de datos? Sí que se puede, sin él irías a ciegas, son comodísimos para ubicarte entre tantas tablas y campos. Hasta phpMyAdmin genera uno similar. Lo que no entiendo es la pregunta que me haces: ¿a qué te refieres con estar hasta arriba? ¿Y con 0>1 || 0>2?